# TinyMCE with Ajax Form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I have set up a form using TinyMCE in my MVC website. To do this, I have an ajaxForm in a partial view like this:

```
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                   (Model.ViewMode == ViewMode.Insert) ? "Create" : "Edit",
                   new AjaxOptions()
                   {
                       UpdateTargetId = CustomerViewModel.WindowContentContainerId,
                       OnFailure = "addValidation"
                       //OnSuccess = "refresh"
                   }))
               {%>

    bla bla

     <p>
                <label for="CustomerBaneer">
                    Baner:</label>
                <%= Html.TextArea(CustomerViewModel.FieldPrefix + "CustomerBaneer", Model.CustomerToEdit.CustomerBaneer)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage(CustomerViewModel.FieldPrefix + "CustomerBaneer", "*")%>
     </p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" />
    <%}%>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas"
                });
            }
    </script>
```

The tinyMce component render well, and I can change my text in bold, underline, etc.. However, when I click on save, the request is send with the textarea content without its formatting (I have monitored it with firebug). Why? Is there any HTML stripping function enables by default with ajax form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U need to save text from tinymce to that textArea before submit.
Function OnBegin is too late, so i did it this way:

```
function tinyToText() {

                ed = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('yourId');

                if (ed) {
                    $("#yourId").val(ed.getContent());
                }
            }

<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="tinyToText();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to add an OnBegin handler to your AjaxOptions to call [tinyMCE.triggerSave()](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/class_tinymce.EditorManager.html#triggerSave) before your form submits. I'm more familiar with jQuery, so you may have to fix up the syntax for the Ajax.BeginForm calls.

```
new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = CustomerViewModel.WindowContentContainerId,
    OnFailure = "addValidation",
    OnBegin = "preSubmit"
    //OnSuccess = "refresh"
}

<script="text/javascript">
  function preSubmit() {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When I use your method, alas, it submits the request as normal post request not a ajax one, so all my page is refresh